# Visual Studio 2017 - Find and replace with text

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio

I have this property in a class:

```
public string fooo { get; set; }
```

I need to rewrite it in something like that :

```
[BsonElement("fooo")] 
public string fooo{ get; set; }
```

I have to do it for a LOT of properties, so I would like to use the 'Find a replace feature' in Visual Studio.

I use the following macro :

```
Search : public 
Replace : [BsonElement("")]\n\t\tpublic
```

How is it possible using regex to get dynamically the `fooo` name and put it in the `BsonElement` property ? And globally, is it possible to have a link to documentation about this, haven't find it.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs(v=vs.140).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution for properties formatted like `public string fooo { get; set; }` (whitespace is important: one-liners, with the space after property name)

Search:

```
(public) (\w+) (\w+) { get; set; }
```

Replace:

```
[BsonElement("$3")]\n\t\t$1 $2 $3 { get; set; }
```

Explanation:

`$1`, `$2`, `$3` are groups captured in `()`

`\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, so `(\w+)` will match any type name and property name

Comment: How is it possible for me to exclude `class` in first w+ and include `? . < >` in the second w+ ?

Comment: Exclude `class`: `((?!class)\w+)` (negative lookahead); Include operators: `([\w?.<>]+)`

Answer (score 1):

Find: `(\s*)public string (\w+) { get; set; }`

Replace: `$1[BsonElement("$2")]\n$1public string $2{ get; set; }`

This solution preserves the whitespace (tabs, etc) before the definition

[Image for your convenience](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grEpm.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Find and Replace(Ctrl + H)
2. Paste `public (\w+) (\w+) { get; set; }` into Find field.
3. Paste `[BsonElement("$2")]\n\t\t public $1 $2 { get; set; }` into Replace field.
4. Enable Regular Expression(Alt+E).
5. Replace all(Alt+A). Or go one by one selectively.

But be aware that if you have some other keywords like `virtual`, `static` etc you will need to more capture groups and change indexes.